# How to DRY and reuse an index view query with Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My application uses Business Areas index query which is quite complex, requiring Arel. This works perfectly for creating the standard Business Areasindex page. Depending on the context, I would like to reuse the same query to list a subset of the index, or feed a hierarchical menu.

So here is the index of Business Areas I would like to DRY:

```
  # GET /business_areas
  # GET /business_areas.json
  def index
    @business_areas = BusinessArea.joins(translated_areas).pgnd(current_playground).visible.search(params[:criteria]).
  select(index_fields).order(order_by).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => paginate_lines)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @business_areas }
      format.csv { send_data @business_areas.to_csv }
      format.js # to make it available to js
    end
  end
```

I try to use this list from a link, with Ajax, to feed a dynamic table:

```
<%= link_to "Business Areas", @business_areas, remote: true, method: :get%>
```

And then process the response with an index.js.erb view such as

```
function(response){
          var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i].id;
                var code = response[i].code;
                var name = response[i].name;
                var playground_id = response[i].playground_id;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + code + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#children tbody").append(tr_str);
            }
```

to fill-up this table:

```
        <table id="children">
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

Apparently, the link with remote: true tries to build the whole index view, and not only data, as it runs several queries related to layout and not specifically the index.

The javaysript does not fill-up the table (is it the right way to implement it?).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think you can use `scope` here for the reusability of this query

Comment: and would recommend you to use this gem https://github.com/globalize/globalize for translations, you'll not have to worry about queries to get translations

Comment: Thanks, globalize did not fulfill my requirements, and I need to fill some divs dynamically, hopefully using Ajax...

Comment: umm, I still believe  `globalize` is a solution for you. you can easily populate data dynamically too